# SpriteKit SKScene initialization

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, initialization, codable

I'm trying to convert my game to use Codable instead of NSCoding and Im having trouble with how to get a game scene initialized.

I've a class call GameScene and 2 subclasses called TownScene and WorldScene. The GameScene doesn't really do anything other than holding some shared variables and functions used by both TownScene and WorldScene.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var isGamePaused: Bool = false
    var destinationMap: String = ""
    var mapEntrance: String = ""
    var dynamicEntities = Set<GKEntity>()
    var staticEntities = Set<StaticEntity>()
    //some other variables

    //some shared functions
}

final class WorldScene: GameScene, Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dynamicEntities
        case staticEntities
        case destinationMap
        case obstacleGraph
        case obstacles
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        super.init()
        
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        destinationMap = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .destinationMap)
        dynamicEntities = try! values.decode(Set<EnemyEntity>.self, forKey: .dynamicEntities)
        staticEntities = try! values.decode(Set<StaticEntity>.self, forKey: .staticEntities)
        //......decoding more stuffs
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(destinationMap, forKey: .destinationMap)
        try container.encode(staticEntities, forKey: .staticEntities)
        //---some other encodings
    }
}
```

I can have the WorldScene encoded without issues, however my question is that whenever a scene is loaded it always calls WorldScene's:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder) 
}
```

How to make it call required init(from decoder: Decoder) instead? Because that's where I'm doing all the decodings to restore a saved scene. Or am I looking in the wrong direction?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: where do you create these scene objects, in a ViewController? if so post that code snippet as well. maybe you're not calling the Decoder init correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you define your scene using Xcode

[image]

it creates an `sks` file

[image]

Then when you load your scene calling

```
GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
```

SpriteKit decodes the `sks` file into a `GameScene` object using the legacy `NSCoding` technology.

This is how SpriteKit is built and you cannot change it because the `sks` file uses the `NSCoding` format.

## Codable

However, what you can do is encoding your `GameScene` instance to a `Data` value using `Encodable`.

```
let gameScene: GameScene = ...
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(gameScene)
```

Now you can decode the `data` value into a `GameScene` instance.

```
let decodedGameScene = try JSONDecoder().decode(GameScene.self, from: data)
```

Of course to do this you need to properly conform your GameScene class to the `Codable` protocol.